# Display Link to Category in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to display the category of an article, and a link to the category. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this on post page you can add something like the following to your single.php file of your theme.

```
<div class="meta">Posted in: <span><?php the_category(', ') ?> </span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here's some info that will be of use:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Basically you can call:  `<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>` and this will output what you're looking for.

Thr `$args` parameter is an array of settings strings that lets you change the order, style, depth etc, on links returned.

Answer (score 2):

Note that: `<?php the_category(', ') ?>`will display the category as a link. which is good.... but if you want only the category  URL (that is, the category link only), then you will have to use the `<?php get_category_link($category_ID); ?>` the `$category_ID` is required. once you fix that in, the category URL will be returned.

Consider the example:

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```

Now you can see how we got the category ID and then using it to get the category Link.
 Hope this answers your question well enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **get_the_category()**

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category ).'" title="'.esc_attr(sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) .'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
}
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```